# What are the reasons for the event scheduler to turn off?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've 4 recurring events in MariaDB 10.1.38, the event scheduler is ON and I've set: `event_scheduler=ON` in my.ini but the scheduler keeps turning off. I currently don't have access to the server logs. Is there any way to determinate why the event scheduler keeps turning off?

Comment: Most common reasons are that 1) you are editing a wrong config or a wrong section of config, and 2) the instance has been upgraded from an older version (or, more likely for 10.1, cross-graded from some MySQL installation), and mysql_upgrade has not been run or failed. In this case, the structure of `mysql.event` remains different from what the scheduler expects, and the scheduler refuses to start. The second will be very visible in server error log, when you get access to it. For checking the first, set some easy option right next to `event_scheduler` and check that the value is picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a way to configure   `event_scheduler=ON`   in `my.cnf`.  (Or remember to run the above SET command after any restarts.)